# Rehabilitation Facilities & Substance Abuse Clinics GIS data in Grand Rapid City MIchigan

Tags: geospatial, drugs

Looking for GIS data for the 57 locations on page 35 of this PDF
https://www.grandrapidsmi.gov/files/assets/public/departments/planning-department/cannabis-data-compendium-7-18-18.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the data from that report on [this interactive map](https://grandrapids.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=e9cedefe358040c3a2bf41670522fc43).

If you have the patience you can click on each point and get its address and x,y coordinates (presumably in Michigan state plane coordinate reference system).

Or, you can [contact the city planner](https://www.grandrapidsmi.gov/Directory/Programs-and-Initiatives/Medical-Marihuana) and request that data.